# Can't reinstall .Net Core SDK after removal "product is already installed"

Tags: .net, windows, installation, error-code, reinstall

I uninstalled .Net Core SDK with "programs and features". When I now try to install the .Net Core SDK again, I get following **Error Code:**

> Error 0x80070666: Process returned error: 0x666
>
> Another version of this product is already installed. Installation of this version cannot continue. To configure or remove the existing version of this product, use Add/Remove Programs on the Control Panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are on Windows, Can you go to

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk
```

Manually remove the SDK you are looking to reinstall.

Comment: I dont have any dotnet folder anymore. The SDK was completly removed.

Comment: Can you go to your command line and type "where dotnet". This will tell you if you have an existing SDK installed (And the location).

Comment: Welp. Where is just a standard CMD command (https://ss64.com/nt/where.html). So... Something bigger going on I would think.

Comment: Yeah. That doesn't look good. Going to reinstall Windows i guess